# How to convert form single click to Double click to Windows form in C#

Tags: c#

How to modify from single click to double clik? Can anyone help me and sorry for my english.

```
private void pbGraph_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // recorder
        string tmpToRecord = "";

        //initialize default brush and pen for drawing
        //pen for making lines, brush to fill the region
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue,1);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);



        //event triggered when left click
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)

        {

            //limit nodes to 5 only
            if (count < 100)
            {
                int currentNodeLocation = whereLocationIs(e.X, e.Y, 10, 10);
                if (currentNodeLocation == 0)
                {

                //add mouse click position to the arraylist
                //increase count everytime a node is created
                count++;
                //store coordinates temporarily
                tmpToRecord = "0," + count.ToString() + "," + e.X.ToString() + "," + e.Y.ToString();
                //store the coordinates based on event click to the array
                arrayForNode[count] = new LocationNodes(e.X, e.Y);

                //get graphics object for picturebox
                Graphics.FromImage(pbGraph.Image).TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                //draw rectangle nodes
                Graphics.FromImage(pbGraph.Image).FillEllipse(brush, arrayForNode[count].returnRectangle());
                //draw numbers aside nodes
                Graphics.FromImage(pbGraph.Image).DrawString(count.ToString(), new Font("Verdana", 8), brush, (float)e.X + 12, (float)e.Y + 12);
                //give status report
                labelStatus.Text = "Status: Node created  " + count;

                //dahSaveKe = false;

                this.Changes = true;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Maximum number of nodes reached");
            }
        }


    //event triggered when right click
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)


    {



        //x denotes the location of node 
        int x = whereLocationIs1(e.X, e.Y);

        if (x != 0)
        {
            if (firstNodeChecked == 0)
            {
                firstNodeChecked = x;
                labelStatus.Text = "Selected Node: " + x.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                if (firstNodeChecked == x)
                {
                    firstNodeChecked = 0;
                    return;
                }

                labelStatus.Text = "Arc is created from " + firstNodeChecked.ToString() + " to " + x.ToString();

                //FormArcValue fav = new FormArcValue();

                //DialogResult dr = fav.ShowDialog(this);

                //if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                //{
                    //limiter for drawing arc
                    if (count < (count * count))
                    {
                        AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);
                        p.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;

                        //draw line as arc to connect between 2 nodes
                        Graphics.FromImage(pbGraph.Image).DrawLine(p,
                            (arrayForNode[firstNodeChecked]._X + 5), (arrayForNode[firstNodeChecked]._Y + 5),
                            (arrayForNode[x]._X + 5), (arrayForNode[x]._Y + 5));

                        Point fa = writeStringInMiddleArcLine(new Point((arrayForNode[firstNodeChecked]._X), 
                            (arrayForNode[firstNodeChecked]._Y)), new Point((arrayForNode[x]._X), (arrayForNode[x]._Y)));

                        //determine which distribution is selected, then
                        //generate random numbers
                            switch (comboCustomer1.Text)
                            {
                                case "Johnson SB":
                                    cost = RandomNumber(costMin, costMax);
                                    demand = RandomNumber(demandMin, demandMax);
                                    break;

                                case "Uniform":
                                    cost = RandomNumber(costMin, costMax);
                                    demand = RandomNumber(demandMin, demandMax);
                                    break;
                            }



                        //write cost and demand for arc
                        Graphics.FromImage(pbGraph.Image).DrawString("(" + demand.ToString("N2") + " , " +
                            cost.ToString("N2") + 
                            ") " + displayCount.ToString(), new Font("Verdana", 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), fa.X, fa.Y);

                        matrixCost[x, firstNodeChecked] = cost;
                        matrixCost[firstNodeChecked, x] = cost;

                        matrixDemand[x, firstNodeChecked] = demand;
                        matrixDemand[firstNodeChecked, x] = demand;

                        //add count and assign demand to the temp matrix
                        matrixDemandDisplay[displayCount] = demand;


                        // put already linked nodes in here
                        linkedNodes[firstNodeChecked, x] = true;
                        linkedNodes[x, firstNodeChecked] = true;

                        // string to record the path
                        tmpToRecord = "1," + x.ToString() + "," + arrayForNode[x]._X.ToString() + "," + arrayForNode[x]._Y.ToString() +
                           "," + firstNodeChecked.ToString() + "," + arrayForNode[firstNodeChecked]._X.ToString() + "," +
                           arrayForNode[firstNodeChecked]._Y.ToString() + "," + demand.ToString() + "," + cost.ToString() + "," +
                           displayCount.ToString();

                        //increase counter
                        displayCount = displayCount + 1;
                        //this.Changes = true;
                    }

                    firstNodeChecked = 0;
                    //dahSaveKe = false;
                }
                //else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
                //{
                //    firstNodeChecked = 0;
                //}

                //labelStatus.Text = "Left click to draw node and right click to link a node";

                //fav.Dispose();
            }

        }


        if (!(tmpToRecord == ""))
        {
            if (!(recordPath == ""))
                recordPath += "|";

            recordPath += tmpToRecord;
        }


        pbGraph.Refresh();
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Whatever you want to do on a single click, just do it.

Comment: I want to try use double click mouse so can anyone help me to modify this coding?

Comment: Nobody really knows what you mean

Comment: What i mean is want to try modify this coding so that i can use double click for my output result. This coding is for single click mouse.

Comment: So what is all the code for?

Comment: Code for arc routing problem. Above coding is to make nodes and arc between two node.

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to your form's Designer.  Right click in the form, choose Properties.  Choose the Events list.  Go to DoubleClick() event.  Double-click on it.  The new Double-Click() event will be put into your source code.  Now, move all your code from within the MouseClick() over to the inside of your new Double-Click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1:** Create a `myMouseDoubleClick` function as below:

```
private void myMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
             //  Cut and Pase your MouseSingleClick Event Code here.
            }
```

**Step2:** Cut and Paste your MouseSingle Click Event Code (in your case `pbGraph_MouseClick`) in the above function.

**Step3:** subscribe the above function `myMouseDoubleClick` to mouse DoubleClick Event.so that whenever mouse Double click event fires it will notify/call all the subscribed functions and your function `myMouseDoubleClick` also be notified.

Subscribe as below:

```
  this.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.myMouseDoubleClick);
```

Comment: I'm very appreciate your help. Thank you sudhakar.

Comment: This is an other question, can you help me? How to do the arrow is just go one way and cannot go back from one point to an other point? You can see in the above coding.

Comment: sorry i did not get you. you want to move mouse pointer only in one way means one direction? could you please give me example?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is coding for arc routing problem. Above coding is to make nodes and arc, then i try to do arrow from node A to node B but when i run the program it still running and it's just not only go from node A to node B but can also from node B to node A back. I just want it to go from node A to node B only.

Answer (score 1):

Find where pbGraph_MouseClick is getting added to your form. Most likely you're using the winforms Designer, in which case it will be in the form's designer file, in which case you would want to change it to a double-click through the GUI interface: create a doubleclick event handler there, then cut-paste all your code from the single-click handler to the new double-click event handler. Then, go back and remove the single-click handler.

Comment: Please, can you show me how to do with simple example or something else?